# eav_attributes not adding to database with setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, attributes, magento-2.0, eav

I am trying to add some custom attributes to my Category page, without success. I created a custom module with its own setup script, after running:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

There are no attributes added to my databsase.
Here are are my module files:

app/code/Forza/CategoriesBanner/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Forza_CategoriesBanner',
    __DIR__
);
```

app/code/Forza/CategoriesBanner/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Forza_CategoriesBanner" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

app/code/Forza/CategoriesBanner/Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php
namespace Forza\CategoriesBanner\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
            $setup->startSetup();

            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
                    'banner_image',
                    [
                        'type'          => 'varchar',
                        'label'         => 'Banner Image',
                        'input'         => 'image',
                        'required'      => false,
                        'sort_order'    => 6,
                        'backend'       => 'Forza\CategoriesBanner\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\CategoryBannerImage',
                        'global'        => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                        'group'         => 'General Information',
                    ]
                );
            $setup->endSetup();
    }
}

?>
```

I am not getting errors on setup:upgrade, so don't really know where to look. What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to add Image attribute then try below code in **InstallData.php**

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;
class InstallData
    implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Category setup factory
     *
     * @var CategorySetupFactory
     */
    private $categorySetupFactory;
    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $setup->startSetup();
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetup $categorySetup */
        $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $categorySetup->addAttribute(
            'catalog_category',
            'banner_image',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Additional Image',
                'input' => 'image',
                'backend' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Image',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 100,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group' => 'General Information',
            ]
        );
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I tried the code above, but no attribute is added to the eav_attributes table. Any suggestions?

Comment: did you replace first line `namespace Namespace\Module\Setup;` with your module and namespace?

Comment: Didnt have a core_resources table, but deleted the 'Forza_CategoriesBanner' row from the setup_module table and tried a setup:upgrade again, now the attribute is added to my database! Thanks a lot!